# How to create array dynamically with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, each

Im trying something which is probably very easy but i cant seem to find out why its not working. Im trying to dynamically create and array with jquery/javascript.

my code;

```
var icons = $('.icon');

var desktopicons = [];

var user = { name: username };

var iconsetup = { myicons: [] };

desktopicons.push(user);
desktopicons.push(iconsetup);

$.each(icons, function() {
        var name = $(this).attr('name');
    var rel = $(this).attr('rel');


    var icon = { 
        icon: [{
            name: name,
            rel: rel
        }]
    };

    iconsetup.myicons[0].push(icon);

});

desktopicons.push(user);
desktopicons.push(iconsetup);

$('#desktop').append(desktopicons[0].name);
$('#desktop').append(desktopicons[1].myicons[0].icon[0].name);
```

Somehow my log file says cannot call method push of undefined on 'iconsetup.myicons[0].push(icon);' this line.

Anyone who can tell me how to create the array? Thanks!

Comment: iconsetup.myicons.push(icon);

Comment: `iconsetup.myicons` is an empty array.

Comment: You don't need the `[0]`, `iconsetup.myicons.push(icon);`

Comment: its unclear to me when to use the [0] and when not.. myicons is an array i thought cuz i declared myicons: [] in var iconsetup

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using `myicons[0]` which means you get the first item of the `myicons` and that is not an array

Use

```
iconsetup.myicons.push(icon);
```

---

You could also simplify the whole `.each()` section with

```
iconsetup.myicons = icons.map(function(idx, item){
   return {icon:[{name: item.name, rel: item.rel}]}
}).get();
```

Comment: its unclear to me when to use the [0] and when not.. myicons is an array i thought cuz i declared myicons: [] in var iconsetup

Comment: @MartijnMichel `myicons` **is** an array, and so `myicons[0]` works but it returns the first item in that array. And that item is not an array.

Comment: any chance you can explain that simplified version, i dont get it ;p

Comment: @MartijnMichel about the `map()` method see http://api.jquery.com/map/ It really is just a slight optimization. If you feel uncomfortable with that code, feel free to ignore it. Your own approach is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to push the icon to `myicons[0]` which is undefined, instead you need to push to myicons which will add the icons to your array:

```
iconsetup.myicons.push(icon);
```

Answer (score 0):

You never set `iconsetup.myicons[0]` *equal* to anything.  `iconsetup.myicons` is simply an empty array with nothing in it, and no element 0.  Maybe you meant:

```
iconsetup.myicons.push(icon);
```